# how to manage multiple environment APK on playstore if it is a cross platform app

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-services, cross-platform, phonegap-build

I have a product for which we have created a mobile application on cross-platform. I am trying to find out if we can manage multiple environments in 1 APK from PLaystore.

I have read many articles but none of them have mentioned anything about a cross platform app. All I got was information about Andriod app for Playstore.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is your problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: I think we can use one Environment at a time. Please elaborate it.

Comment: 1 have two different database and would like to manage both the database from 1 apk.  The issue is i am not able to find any information on how to manage two database from 1 APK if it is a cross platform application. I want my users to use the live database and also want our testing team to be able to access test database from same APK

Comment: What is reason behind one apk only?
Why not make separate apk for it?

Comment: for same application playstore shall not allow two apk's

Comment: Put user type in login, If user is tester then point "TEST" database and for live user point "LIVE" database